# Citrix Remote Tracking

Tags: citrix

Can screen shares be detected/tracked when using Citrix-receiver to remote into office desktop?

Can other tools in addition to Citrix be used to monitor employees?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible? Or if you can do it? Or if your employer can?

Comment: Can my employer do it?

Answer (score 1):

Citrix has session monitoring built into XenApp and XenDesktop. You can read an overview [here](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-15-ltsr/monitor.html#session-recording), but for completeness sake here is a list of a few of the capabilities that an administrator would have in a typical XenApp or XenDesktop environment:

- Read an audit log of which users opened sessions, when, and to where
- Record sessions as a whole (to video)
- Record keystrokes and mouse movements
- See a screenshot of a session
- See a session's process list
- Kill processes on a session
- Run commands on the session